# Get values after keyword until next keyword from string

Tags: python, string

I have a string:

`entry: 1.0 - 2.0 stop:1.0 tp: 3.0, 4.0 risk:   medium, type: Long`

String originally is list of all words that I combine with a simple for loop:

```
final_string = ""
for element in string_list:
    final_string += element + " "

string_list would be = ("entry:", "1.0", "-", "2.0", "stop:1.0", "tp:", "3.0,", "4.0", "risk:",   "medium,", "type:", "Long",)
```

I want to extract one by one each value to a certain variable, result would be:

```
entry = " 1.0 - 2.0 "
stop = "1.0 "
tp = " 3.0, 4.0 "
risk = "   medium, "
type = " Long"
```

At first I wanted to append each word to a string until I stumbled upon a member of list of all possible keywords - `["entry:", "stop:", "tp:", "risk:", "type:", "info:", "lev:"]`
but after trying it, my only idea of implementation was both non-optimal and didn't find values that weren't seperated by `' '` (space) from keyword.

Comment: What is `string_list`?

Comment: Show the contents of `string_list`, I doubt it will be easier to parse the string you create from it. Also, do you really want leading and trailing space in values?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi edited post. It's passed as "*args" in function arguments. It's a tuple.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that an item of `string_list` that contains a colon is supposed to be a keyword?

Comment: And how do you create the list in the first place?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, because one possible keyword is "info:" and it is possible for it to contain it, but if you have an idea then please post it as an answer, it might be helpful for me later on.

Comment: @buran it's bassicaly a list of arguments following a command in discord (I'm creating discord bot), so when a user types >call entry: 1.0 stop: 0.8 lev: 20x it would pass tuple ("entry:", "1.0", "stop:", "0.8", "lev:", "20x",) as a argument in the event-handling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is actually a good tool for this, if we use a lookahead.

```
import re

st = "entry: 1.0 - 2.0 stop:1.0 tp: 3.0, 4.0 risk:   medium, type: Long"

keywords = dict(re.findall(r'(\w*)\:(.*?)(?=\w*\:|$)', st))
# {'entry': ' 1.0 - 2.0 ', 
#  'stop': '1.0 ', 
#  'tp': ' 3.0, 4.0 ', 
#  'risk': '   medium, ', 
#  'type': ' Long'}
```

To break down the regex used:

```
(\w*)\:(.*?)(?=\w*\:|$)

(\w*)                    capture continous word characters (no spaces)
     \:                  followed by a literal ':', which we ignore
       (.*?)             capture any character, non-greedy
            (?=       )  and stop capturing when the following is ahead
               \w*\:     another keyword (continuous word characters followed by ':')
                    |    or
                     $   the end of the string
```

If you want the `:` to be included as part of the keyword itself, then just move the `\:` to inside the first capture of the regular expression: `(\w*\:)(.*?)(?=\w*\:|$)`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be creating separate variables to hold each key (see [How do I create a variable number of variables](//stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/843953)). It's much better to create a dictionary with those keys.

```
keys = []
vals = []

for item in string_list:
    if ":" in item:
        # Split item by :
        kk = item.split(":", 1)
        # First element of kk is the key, so 
        # Add a new key
        keys.append(kk[0])
        # Add a new list to hold values for this key
        # Any subsequent elements of kk are part of the value. 
        vals.append(kk[1:])
    else:
       # Append item to last element of vals
        vals[-1].append(item)
```

Now, you have:

```
keys = ['entry', 'stop', 'tp', 'risk', 'type']

vals = [['', '1.0', '-', '2.0'],
 ['1.0'],
 ['', '3.0,', '4.0'],
 ['', 'medium,'],
 ['', 'Long']]
```

To create your dictionary, you can iterate over `keys` and `vals`, joining all the items in each `vals` entry. Using `str.join()` to join the elements of each `vals` entry, you can even filter out the blank values.

```
result = {
    k: " ".join(v_elem for v_elem in v if v_elem) 
    for k, v in zip(keys, vals)
}
```

Which gives the following dict:

```
{'entry': '1.0 - 2.0',
 'stop': '1.0',
 'tp': '3.0, 4.0',
 'risk': 'medium,',
 'type': 'Long'}
```